# Nifi escape pipe character Jolt Transform

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

Is there a way to escape the pipe character (`|`) in JoltTransformJSON Processor on NiFi?

I have a Json with many attributes names having that charcater, and I need to flatten it using JoltTransform, but if I use the pipe character in the JoltTransform spec, I get a warning saying the spec is invalid. It works fine when I replace all `|` with underscores though.

I guess one way to avoid this would be to use replaceText before and after the JoltTransform Processor, but is there a more convenient way to do this?

(Of course I tried escaping with `\\` but it doesn't work, I get the same warning.)

[UPDATE]
Here is the what the input Json looks like :

```
[
  {
    "root": "value",
    "first|Level|Array": [
      {
        "firstLevel": [
          "value1"
        ],
        "second|Level|Array": [
          {
            "secondLevel": [
              "value2"
            ]
          },
          {
            "secondLevel": [
              "value3"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And here is the expected output :

```
{
  "root" : "value",
  "first|Level|Array|firstLevel" : [ "value1" ],
  "second|Level|Array[0]|secondLevel" : [ "value2" ],
  "second|Level|Array[1]|secondLevel" : [ "value3" ]
}
```

And the Jolt spec I was hoping to use :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "first|Level|Array": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&2\\|&",
            "second|Level|Array": {
              "*": {
                "*": "&2\\[&1\\]\\|&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you post your input and expected output json

Comment: Sure! I edited the post to add them, also added the Jolt spec I'm trying to use